# How to use Bootstrap-select in Blazor Server App

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to use Bootstrap-select in Blazor Server app, i did all steps from Bootstrap-select website(https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) to my blazor server app and also install bootstrap-select package from NuGet package manager but there is no effect to select element. Is it possible to use Bootstrap-select in blazor app. I will be very thankful if somebody help.

[image]
[image]
It is my razor Component:

```
@page "/"

    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used the library javascript files but are missing multiple dependencies: jQuery and bootstrap js files. bootstrap-select requires Bootstrap js and Bootstrap js requires jQuery and `popper.js`

You need to read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) on how to fully add bootstrap js files. After that you can use any other Bootstrap based javascript library.

Preferably, you will also need to call the bootstrap-select init code after the page has rendered.

See the below javascript code:

```
window.InitSelectPicker = (dotnetHelper, callbackMethodName, pickerElementName) => {

    // initialize the specified picker element
    $(pickerElementName).selectpicker();

    // setup event to push the selected dropdown value back to c# code
    $(pickerElementName).on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync(callbackMethodName, $(pickerElementName).val());
    });    
}
```

Note the [`changed.bs.select` event](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#events) being called. which will get the selected value.

See the razor file with c# code to init and callback selected value:

```
// inject jsruntime to call javascript code
[Inject] public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

// hold the callback selected value
public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

// call the javascript method to init the select picker
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender) // only needs to be called once per page render
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("InitSelectPicker", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), "OnSelectedValue", ".selectpicker");
    }
}

// method which will be triggered by javascript, need to pass the method name 
[JSInvokable]
public void OnSelectedValue(string val)
{
    SelectedValue = val;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Complete source code [here](https://github.com/umair-me/BlazorServer-BootstrapSelect)

Comment: When invoking from js, if you cast the value to string you can support the multiple attribute. `dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync(callbackMethodName, String($(pickerElementName).val()));`