# Boostrap-select Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am following this but en blazor WASM:
[How to use Bootstrap-select in Blazor Server App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798054/how-to-use-bootstrap-select-in-blazor-server-app/62799831#62799831)

the problem is that every time I rerun my page or any other, several select are created

Comment: May be this library can help you to avoid using bootstrap select. https://github.com/Blazored/Typeahead I use it in blazor.

Comment: it was what I was looking for thanks!